# PyQt modules can't be imported after QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.5, pyqt5, python-import

**OVERVIEW**

I'm having troubles importing modules after the line 
`QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)`, let's say I got this little snippet `main.py`:

```
import sys
import importlib
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

print('Sys Path:')
print('  %s\n' % '\n  '.join(sys.path))

if sys.argv[-1] == '1':
    print('Importing Before...\n')
    from PyQt5 import Qt
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

elif sys.argv[-1] == '2':
    print('Importing After...\n')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    from PyQt5 import Qt

print('Done')
```

- If I run `python main.py 1` everything works as expected.
- If I run `python main.py 2` the process hangs (probably in a infinite loop) without giving any error.

Output of `python main.py 2`:

```
(py352) D:\sources\personal\python\pyqt\mcve>python main.py 2           
Sys Path:                                                               
  D:\sources\personal\python\pyqt\mcve                                  
  D:\sources\personal\python                                            
  d:\virtual_envs\py352\Scripts\python35.zip                            
  d:\virtual_envs\py352\DLLs                                            
  d:\virtual_envs\py352\lib                                             
  d:\virtual_envs\py352\Scripts                                         
  c:\Python352\Lib                                                      
  c:\Python352\DLLs                                                     
  d:\virtual_envs\py352                                                 
  d:\virtual_envs\py352\lib\site-packages                               

Importing After...                                                      
(HANG)
```

**ATTEMPTS**

Tested with a couple of virtualenvs on win7:

- `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` on `win7`
- `Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Pyqt was installed on the virtualenvs using pip and the versions are these ones:

```
>>> QtCore.QT_VERSION
329472
>>> QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
'5.7.0'
>>> QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
'5.7'
```

**RELEVANT INFORMATION**

Some very nice people from `#pyqt freenode` channel helped me to test the repo and none of them were able to reproduce the issue, the python versions and platforms they used were:

- win10        - 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)
- win8         - 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18)
- ubuntu 16.04 - 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)

**QUESTIONS**

- What's the reason of `from PyQt5 import Qt` (or others pyqt modules) getting stuck on my box and other people not being able to reproduce?
- How can I fix this behaviour? This is important to me cos I'd like to load plugins dynamically once my pyqt applications has started

Comment: One concrete suggestion: create a test script that simply attempts to execute `importlib.import_module(mod_name)` before and after creating a `QApplication`. If it still hangs, you have your mcve; if it doesn't hang, you'll know for certain that you haven't debugged your test case enough. It should be possible to refactor `list_plugins` into a stand-alone function. You can then just point it at any directory containing `*.py` files and see if it still hangs. The idea is to isolate just one small section of code that causes the problem and eliminate *everything* else.

Comment: Can you please try the two suggestions I made in my previous comments? It should only be about ten minutes work and it will allow you to post a proper mcve. The other stuff is probably irrelevant - this is almost certainly an issue that is specific to your particular setup.

Comment: @ekhumoro Alright, I've updated the repo once again, If you got some time, please let me know if you see something else that could be improved further in order to decrease the complexity even more.

Comment: Can you please put the code in the question so everybody can see the what you are actually testing? If you followed my earlier suggestions, you should end up with just one small file. Also, you need to state clearly exactly what happens when you run the test, because you are currently the only one who can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro Alright, I've followed your advice, the result is right now people either can see the repo's content in this question or also clone the repo contents if they find it a faster way to give it a shot. I haven't been able to simplify further the test case and as you can see the result is a set of 5 files (don't know why you said before i'd end up with just one small file), I'm still unsure what's the benefit of putting the code in the question instead of doing `git clone`... but let's give it a shot cos this problem has been bothering me already for few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not (yet) a real answer, but it might provide the first step in how to find one.

Below is the minimal test case I suggested in my first comment on the question. It tests just **one** thing: does calling `importlib.import_module` after creating a `QApplication` make the interpreter hang on your system? Note that, for now, it only tries to import a module from the python standard library. It is vital to proceed one step at a time, and be careful to avoid introducing any potentially confounding variables.

Please run this script *exactly as described below*, and add the output to your question. (Even if option 2 doesn't hang, the `sys.path` details are likely to be relevant).

```
import sys, importlib
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

print('Sys Path:')
print('  %s\n' % '\n  '.join(sys.path))

mod = None
modname = 'collections.abc'
# modname = 'PyQt5.Qt'

if sys.argv[-1] == '1':
    print('Importing Before...\n')
    mod = importlib.import_module(modname)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

elif sys.argv[-1] == '2':
    print('Importing After...\n')
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mod = importlib.import_module(modname)
    # from PyQt5 import Qt

print('Result: %r' % mod)
```

Run the script like this:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py 1
```

then like this:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py 2
```

On my system (ArchLinux, Python-3.5.2, Qt-5.7.1, PyQt-5.7), the second one produces the following output:

```
Sys Path:
  /tmp
  /usr/lib/python35.zip
  /usr/lib/python3.5
  /usr/lib/python3.5/plat-linux
  /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
  /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Importing After...

Result: <module 'collections.abc' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/abc.py'>
```

**UPDATE**:

The first step established that `importlib` is not itself the cause of the problem. The second step is to identify which specific imported module is the source of the problem.

I have added two (commented) lines to the test script that will allow this to be done. The first checks whether importing `PyQt5.Qt` triggers a hang. If it does, the second checks whether a normal `import` statement will also trigger the hang.

Note that `from PyQt5 import Qt` effectively imports *everything*, including some very heavyweight and potentially troublesome modules like `QtWebEngineWidgets`. So it will be necessary to further refine the imports to properly identify the precise source of the problem.

**UPDATE 2**:

The `QtWebEngineWidgets` is a well-known source of problems, and often needs careful handling. The following interpreter session output seems relevant to your current problem:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
>>> app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute before constructing QGuiApplication.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: QtWebEngineWidgets must be imported before a QCoreApplication instance is created
>>>
>>> QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: QtWebEngineWidgets must be imported before a QCoreApplication instance is created
```

This is all normal behaviour (although at the moment I can't find any official documentation for it). But let's try the same thing using the `Qt` module:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
>>> QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
>>> app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])
>>> from PyQt5 import Qt
>>> Qt.QWeb
Qt.QWebChannel(                      Qt.QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(  Qt.QWebHitTestResult(                Qt.QWebSocketCorsAuthenticator(
Qt.QWebChannelAbstractTransport(     Qt.QWebEngineUrlRequestJob(          Qt.QWebInspector(                    Qt.QWebSocketProtocol(
Qt.QWebDatabase(                     Qt.QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler(       Qt.QWebPage(                         Qt.QWebSocketServer(
Qt.QWebElement(                      Qt.QWebFrame(                        Qt.QWebPluginFactory(                Qt.QWebView(
Qt.QWebElementCollection(            Qt.QWebHistory(                      Qt.QWebSecurityOrigin(
Qt.QWebEngineCookieStore(            Qt.QWebHistoryInterface(             Qt.QWebSettings(
Qt.QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo(         Qt.QWebHistoryItem(                  Qt.QWebSocket(
>
```

So it looks like there's special handling for the `Qt` module when it's imported *after* a `QApplication` is created - although *some* `QWebEngine` classes are available, most of them have been omitted (e.g. `QWebEngineView`, `QWebEnginePage`, etc). But it seems that in your particular setup, this may not be working as it should. If so, you'd probably have to take this up with the author of PyQt, as it might require knowledge of the inner workings of the `Qt` module.

Comment: First of all, thanks for a first attempt of helping, hopefully this will inspire others to contribute with some new ideas. I must to say it's a good idea you've merged {main_ok.py, main_bug.py} into test.py, later on I'll update the repo & question to simplify that. Unfortunately your test won't show up any issue (no hanging) on my box. One thing you'll see in the last commit of my repo is the file `gui\operator_object.py` containing `from PyQt5 import Qt`... but before i got `from PyQt5.Qt import qDrawShadeRect`, I've realized both of them are producing the hang here on my box.

Comment: Also, one relevant detail, if I replace `from PyQt5 import Qt` in `gui\operator_object.py` by `import collections.abc` i won't experience the hang. So it seems for some reason are PyQt modules the ones who are allowing me to reproduce the bug over here. +1 for your time & help btw ;D

Comment: @BPL. So now I've shown you how to test things properly, you should be able to do the rest on your own. If you proceed in small steps, carefully checking each element in isolation, you will eventually find the real source of the problem. It would be helpful if you changed the title and most of the content of your question, since I've now established beyond doubt that `import_module` does not *by itself* cause the problem.

Comment: @BPL. I've taken the liberty of adding the next step to my answer. Please try out the new tests and confirm whether they reproduce the problem. If they do, that should completely eliminate `import_lib` and the plugins as the cause. It would also be helpful if you could edit your question and state the exact versions of Qt5 and PyQt5 you are testing with, and how you installed them (i.e. are they from binary installers, a wheel, compiled from source, etc).

Comment: Alright, thanks to you, the question has been simplified ad-maximum and we've constrained a little bit more the problem. If I knew in the first place this was the real problem I would have provided this type of `mcve` directly in the question. So, what'd you suggest that should be the next step to figure out the issue? Also, what do you think it was my mistake in the first place to delay that much the creation of the real mcve? I've got stuck with the idea importlib was buggy for some reason and I've wasted a lot of time. I ask this cos I'd like to improve my debug skills next time

Comment: I've found out which one is the problematic module, it seems is `QtWebEngineWidgets` the guilty one. I've tried all PyQt5 modules one by one... now, any other suggestion to fix this?

Comment: @BPL. The simplest fix would simply be: don't import the `Qt` module. As you've now discovered, it loads a whole mess of stuff you don't actually need (the `qDrawShadeRect` function can be imported from the `QtWidgets` module). The `QtWebEngineWidgets` module in particular is well-known for causing hard to debug problems. I've added another update to my answer which expands on this in a few ways that are probably pertinent to your own issue.

Comment: One remaining question before validating your answer, what's the version/source(pip, sources, installer,...) of your pyqt distribution? Asking you this cos you're getting that whole bunch of useful information I don't and I'd like to know why... As stated in the question i've just installed from Pypi. Btw, i've already posted on pyqt mailing list, hopefully Phil will take a look at it

Comment: @BPL. My dev machine is arch-linux, and I mostly use the official binary packages - but sometimes compile from source. I don't know why you aren't seeing what I do - how exactly are you testing? Do you start the python interpreter from a console (or whatever it's called on Windows)?

Comment: I  use SublimeText with a package which allows me to run my script with all my virtualenvs availables, i never execute python scripts with all my python system-wide installations. Since pyqt has been published on pypi i've never compiled from sources again. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, this one was a really tricky one

Answer (score 0):

Using these lines in your code after importing libraries will help.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
if app is not None:
    import sip
    app.quit()
    sip.delete(app)
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWebEngineWidgets
QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
app = QtWidgets.qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.